# Difference between setting hostname using binary and setting hostname in file in Linux

Tags: linux, hostname

In Linux, I can change the hostname as follows:

```
sudo hostname <hostname>
```

Additionally, I can just change the hostname in the `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` file.

My question is: If I change the hostname in the files, do I still need to call `sudo hostname <hostname>` or not? What does this command do in addition to change the hostname in the `/etc/hostname` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "active" hostname is actually stored in the kernel. Programs don't use /etc/hostname directly; the file is only read once at boot time to initialize the kernel hostname.

Specifically, on Linux, the 'hostname' command will set the sysctl parameter `kernel.hostname` (by writing to `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`), and all programs will look there for the system's current hostname.

Most likely it works this way for historical reasons – Unix programs have used [uname()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) for a long time to get the current hostname together with the OS version, and uname() has been a kernel syscall for a long time, so even though the kernel doesn't *do* much with the hostname it'll still store and return it.

Comment: I think to set hostname, the `sethostname` syscall is made, as seen by `strace`.